# Happiness only real when shared... isn't it?

Tags: grammar

Yesterday I was rewatching the movie "Into the Wild", and noticed that protagonist writes next phrase:

> HAPPINESS ONLY REAL WHEN SHARED

and, I'm not native english speaker, but is he missed the `is`? Should it be:

> HAPPINESS `IS` ONLY REAL WHEN SHARED

or it's ok to skip `is` in that particular case?

[image]

Comment: I've closevoted as General Reference. Igor - questions at this level would be better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). In general you should assume the verb **is** is grammatically required in cases like this. But personal jottings, newspaper headlines, etc., don't always follow "the rules".

Comment: and talking about newspaper headlines, we are talking about NY Times level or some yellow press?

Comment: @ igor: I doubt the calibre of journalistic research (or the "reputation" of the newspaper) would make any difference, to be honest. As p.s.w.g notes, "headlinese" has its own rules (or lack of them! :). But in your case it's not even that - it's just some guy scribbling a note on a book. Hardly worth considering, in terms of "grammaticality".

Comment: I don't know the context in the film, but if you are writing notes *to yourself*, provided no-one else needs to read it, you can write it in whatever form you want - shorthand, 'double dutch', abbreviations, ... whatever. The rules of grammar don't apply when writing notes to yourself!

Comment: Many rules of grammar still apply when writing notes to yourself, since you want to be able to understand the notes later. English always has grammar. It's just a different set of rules than you would use if you were writing to other people.

Comment: @bdsl Debatable - but this is not the place to discuss it. I merely meant that the **only** requirement is that "you want to be able to understand the notes later", so - with that proviso - you can use whatever language, dialect, grammar, etc. you care to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of construction would not be accepted as grammatical by the vast majority of English speakers for general use. However, it's quite common when writing annotations, short notes, or in other limited contexts to drop, '*is*', '*are*' or other words that can be clearly inferred from the context. The full sentence should be read as:

> Happiness [is] only real when [it is] shared

This abbreviated use of language is similar to [Headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Comment: good answer. So, just to clarify a little bit, are all these people  made a huge mistake, and this phrase looks grammatically incorrect without knowing the context? [link](https://www.google.com/search?gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=56RBLxh3_8ZnSoEd9isLUg&pq=happiness+only+real+when++shared&cp=34&gs_id=8&xhr=t&q=happiness+only+real+when+shared+tattoo&safe=active&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.ZWU&biw=1846&bih=995&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=uk&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=gW7LUZHXAsXaPPDigKAJ)

Comment: 'Not grammatically correct'? The link given by p.s.w.g. contains 'The vocabulary and grammatical constructs used in headlines have become so culturally ingrained that they are often encountered even where there are no space constraints.' There is no grammar czar to adjudicate when a usage becomes 'so culturally ingrained' that it ceases to be 'not grammatically correct'.

Comment: @igormilla It's not grammatically correct, but I imagine the people that chose to get "*HAPPINESS ONLY REAL WHEN SHARED*" tattoos know full well what the context is (and probably like the fact that it's not grammatically correct as a sort of inside reference).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's true, but this construction is generally accepted only within limited contexts. I've updated my answer with wording that should be a bit more acceptable.